# How to create service container in symfony2 for a custom class

Tags: php, symfony

i'm new to symfony2 and getting hard time to inject services into my custom class. Following is the Scenario:
In Bundle, i created a folder and a class inside it. In that bundle, services.yml has the following code

```
parameters:
    rc2ab_model.class: rc2ab\ShareBundle\Model\Rc2abModel
services:
    rc2ab_model:
        class: "%rc2ab_model.class%"
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

This is the constructor of the custom class

```
public function __construct($em) {

}
```

After this when i create Object of Rc2abModel Class in DefaultController

```
$myObj = new Rc2abModel();
```

Error comes:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for rc2ab\ShareBundle\Model\Rc2abModel::__construct(), called in Default Controller....
```

I am not able to fix this out, i have read the documentation on their site, so please don't give me documentation link, i have tried other solution here but nothing seems to work for me. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service is called like that in the controller, you don't have to initial it yourself :

```
$myObj = $this->get('rc2ab_model');
```

It will result the object with given arguments from the service registration ^^

Try this now :

```
echo get_class($this->get('rc2ab_model')); exit;

// Display :
rc2ab\ShareBundle\Model\Rc2abModel
```

Comment: Thanks :)
last time i ended up doing this thing.. but didn't checked that i'm getting any arg in constructor.